# Extracting features and using machine learning on signal which is not oscillating around 0

Tags: machine-learning, signal-processing

In the literature machine learning techniques are applied to signals which are oscilating around 0.
If this is not the case (like on the image below), can feature extraction and machine learning still be succesfully applied?

[image: Signal not oscillating around 0]

Comment: Can you give your source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, as long as your signal is a stationary ergodic process**.

Depending on what you have to do and how you want to do it, there are a plenty of methods you can use.

If you really want your case to be "like the ones inside your textbook" you can just estimate the average and remove it from every sample.